# Google Play Games Services in Ionic React (Capacitor)

Tags: android, react-native, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I'm writing a game in Ionic React - which forces the use of Capacitor.

There is no real Capacitor plugin. Normally in Capacitor, you could use Cordova plugins with the appropriate wrapper, as documented [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react). So I installed as instructed [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-play-games-services), but now Android Studio throws up a bunch of build errors like those:

```
...\appname\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\berriart\cordova\plugins\GameHelper.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Invitation
  location: package com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer

...\appname\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\berriart\cordova\plugins\GameHelper.java:43: 

error: package com.google.android.gms.games.request does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;
```

[This user](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-play-services/185623) suggested use of the package `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release`, that didn't solve the issue (as expected, since I'm not using Cordova).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this plugin.](https://github.com/openforge/capacitor-game-services)

You can install it with `npm i openforge/capacitor-game-services` into your capacitor project.

Follow the instructions on the GitHub page to the end before trying to fix errors plopping up.